# Getting the count from two tables in Apache HIVE or SQL

Tags: sql, hadoop, mapreduce, hive, bigdata

So I have two tables: 
table_1 and table_2

They both have various columns with the same name.

We only need to work with 2 columns:
ID and REGION

table_1 has ID fields that are distinct to table_1 only.
table_2 has ID fields that are distinct to table_2 only.

however, some ID fields are shared by both table_1 and table_2

I need to write a query where i get the number of different ID fields from both tables where REGION = '1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A FULL OUTER JOIN should do the trick.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM table_1 
FULL OUTER JOIN table_2 ON (table_1.id=table_2.id)
```

It will create a single row for every id that is either in table_1 or table_2. If the id is in both tables, it will still create a single row.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL, take advantage of a UNION to eliminate duplicate values between the two tables, so you're left with a distinct list of ID values to count.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (SELECT ID
              FROM table_1
              WHERE REGION = '1'
          UNION
          SELECT ID
              FROM table_2
              WHERE REGION = '1') t
```